# Create HTML element from within for loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am using Javascript to create and populate an HTML table from an array.
This code works perfectly fine:

```
var i = 0;
while (i < headers.length){
    var titleCell = titles.insertCell(i);
    titleCell.innerHTML = headers[i];
    i++;
}
```

However when I replace it with the following for loop it completely stops working. The cells are no longer created or populated.:

```
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++;){
    var titleCell = titles.insertCell(i);
    titleCell.innerHTML = headers[i];
}
```

I'm very confused about the difference between the two. Why would the while loop work but not the for loop?

EDIT: The problem is not the declaration of `i`. I have tried `var i = 0;`  and even declaring `i` before running the loop. Neither of them made any difference.
I do get an error in my console but it's not about the declaration of `i` at all. The error is:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control

but the line of code is perfect as far as I can tell:

```
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++;){
```

Here is my complete code for the page:

```js
   function submitClient() {
    if (window.opener != null && !window.opener.closed) {
     var txtName = window.opener.document.getElementById("clientID");
     txtName.value = document.getElementById("customerID").value;
    }
    window.close();
   }
   var columnTitles = ["User ID", "First Name", "Last Name"];
   var clientList = JSON.parse('[{"ID":55,"firstName":"blabla","lastName":"bla"},{"ID":56,"firstName":"blabla","lastName":"bla"},{"ID":57,"firstName":"blabla","lastName":"bla"}]');
   function createTable(headers, data) {
    // Create table.
    var table = document.createElement('table');
    // Insert New Row for table at index '0'.
    var titles = table.insertRow(0);
    for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++;){
     var titleCell = titles.insertCell(i);
     titleCell.innerHTML = headers[i];
    }
    var div = document.getElementById('dataTable');
    div.appendChild(table);
   }
   createTable(columnTitles, clientList);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <body>
  <form>
   Client ID: <input type="text" id="customerID"><br>
   <input type="button" value="Select" onclick="submitClient();" />
  </form>
  <div id="dataTable"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can see the error that it gives in the snippet.

Comment: what if you add var before i : for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++;){

Comment: The only significant difference is that you've failed to declare `i` in the second example. If you're running in strict mode, that's an error. If not, it's an *implicit global*.

Comment: Define "stops working" in more detail.

Comment: @user1803425 Please see my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second example you missed the `var` keyword in your for loop. You also put an `;` after the `i++` part. That is where your console error is coming from.

```
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++){
```

You'll likely see a JS error in your browser console if you check it before making the change.

Comment: I do get an error but it's completely unrelated to i. I get an error saying: missing ) after for loop control.

Answer (score 2):

You have to declare a variable i inside of for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++;){
  var titleCell = titles.insertCell(i);
  titleCell.innerHTML = headers[i];
}
```

Comment: Makes no difference. Still the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are not declaring `i` as an variable in the for loop.
Declare the `i` variable by appending the `var` before it, like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; i++;){
  var titleCell = titles.insertCell(i);
  titleCell.innerHTML = headers[i];
}
```